# How to point a domain to a subdomain from Laravel? (dns settings)

Tags: laravel, dns, devops, saas

I have a app where each user can have their own store on a dedicated subdomain, for example: shop1.saas.app

If I want a domain like myshop.com to point to a subdomain like sub.saas.app, how to do the DNS settings?

Assuming that both domains are parked on the Liara dns service. (liara is Cloud service provider) And the subdomain sub.saas.app is from a Laravel program.

I created an ALIAS record in the myshop.com domain settings that points to the subdomain sub.saas.app; Actually, now I expect that when I enter the myshop.com site, the content of the sub.saas.app subdomain will be displayed. But Liara's 404 page is displayed.

[image: dns setting]